# An estimation of the number of prime in the form $4n+3$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Suppose we define $f(x)$ to be the number of prime of the form $4n+3$ that is smaller or equal to $x$, what are some of the simple estimation of this function?

Answer (score 1):

$$  \frac{x}{2 \log x},  $$
logarithm base $$  e \approx 2.71828$$

Comment: Does this result come from that there exist appoximately same number of primes of the form 4n+1 and 4n+3? Would you please elaborate on this result?

Comment: @Rikka  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Prime_number_theorem_for_arithmetic_progressions